# What is temperature distribution equation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have $T(x,y)$ (a function of two variables $x$ and $y$) and it is the temperature distribution on a metal plate.

What does temperature distribution mean? what does its equation say? if I have the equation of the temperature distribution of the plate, can I find the equation of the plate itself? or can I say anything about the plate?

**Context of the question:** $T:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $T(x,y)=x^2+y^3$. A robot traverses a path $c:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $c(t)=\left(t,\sin\left(\frac{t\pi}{2}\right)\right)$. I need to explain why the robot remains on the plate but I do not have the equation of the plate and I am puzzled.

Comment: Presumably, $T(x, y)$ gives you the temperature at a given point $(x, y)$ on the plate.  I would assume that it is also assumed to be at a given time, unless the plate is at equilibrium.

Comment: @Kaynex: please see my comment above.

Comment: @user62977 You shoud add the information from your last comment to the body of the question

Comment: It's fair to say that if the temperature distribution is defined on $[0,1], [0,1]$ then the plate is square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background:** The equation describing the temperature distribution in a piece of material is usually called [heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Statement_of_the_equation). It is a partial differential equation (PDE)  and has two main forms:

(A) time-dependent heat equation:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \alpha\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z^2}\right).
$$

(B) steady-state heat equation
$$
\alpha\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z^2}\right)=0.
$$
The coefficient $\alpha$ characterizes the material and is called
*thermal diffusivity*; $u$ is the temperature; $x,y,z$ are spatial coordinates, and $t$ is time. The thermal diffusivity $\alpha$ may be constant or it may depend on coordinates and/or time. An additional term representing *internal heat generation* may also appear in the equation.

To solve the heat equation and find the temperature distribution, we need
boundary conditions on the surface of the material as well as, in case (A), 
the initial condition (i.e. the temperature distribution at the time $t=0$).

The $T(x,y)$ in the problem statement gives temperature as a function of spatial coordinates $x,y$; therefore $u=T(x,y)$ must be *a solution of the heat equation* (for some $\alpha$ and some particular form of internal heat generation). So in this problem you do not need to *solve* the heat equation because you are already given a particular solution (spatial distribution of temperature): $T(x,y)=x^2+y^3$ in the *square plate* $x\in[0,1]$, $y\in[0,1]$.

**In this particular problem about a robot's motion:** The robot's path is already given as a parametric curve $c(t)=(x(t),y(t))=(t,\sin{t\pi\over2})$. The parametric equation $(x,y)=(t,\sin{t\pi\over2})$ maps the parameter $t\in[0,1]$ to coordinates $(x,y)$.  The given parametric equation of the robot's path guarantees that both $x$ and $y$ are within $[0,1]$ because
$$
\qquad\qquad x = t, \ \ t\in[0,1] \quad\Rightarrow\quad x\in[0,1],
$$
$$
\ y = \sin(t\pi/2), \ \ t\in[0,1] \quad\Rightarrow\quad y\in[0,1].
$$

So in this (part of) problem, there is apparently no need to solve (or even know) the general form of the heat equation.

Comment: $T:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $T(x,y)=x^2+y^3$. A robot traverses a path $c:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $c(t)=\left(t,\sin\left(\frac{t\pi}{2}\right)\right)$. I need to explain why the robot remains on the plate but I do not have the equation of the plate and I am puzzled.

Comment: The plate here is a square $x\in[0,1], \ y\in[0,1]$. You are already given a solution to the heat equation $T(x,y)=x^2+y^3$. This is a steady state, i.e. there is no temperature dependence on time $t$. (Physically, this solution would most likely be possible if there is some spatial variabililty in $\alpha$, i.e. $\alpha\ne{\rm const}$ for your case.)

Comment: How do you know that the plate is square? $x\in[0,1], \ y\in[0,1]$ is for the domain of the temperature distribution and not the plate itself. and how does that help to explain why the robot remains on the plate?

Comment: Temperature exists and can be measured at points $(x,y)$, $0\le x \le1$, $0\le y \le1$. Your problem statement says it's temperature of the plate, hence $(x,y)$ are coordinates of points of the (2-dimensional) plate.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I still can not see why the robot remains on the surface. Can you help?

Comment: I added more detailed explanation at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry that I do not have enough reputations to upvote your answer but I have already accepted your answer.